# Generating PDF using chrome-aws-lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a lambda function in nodejs which fetches the handlebar template from s3 and generates the HTML and converts as PDF and uploads it in s3. After deploying the lambda to AWS, when I test it. It executes without error but no PDF or HTML has been generated.

```
try {

  const temp = result.Body.toString(); //.replace(/\\|\\n/g,'');

  console.log(temp);

  const template = hbs.compile(temp);
  const html = template(data);

  console.log(html);

  const executablePath = event.isOffline
    ? "./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-674921/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium"
    : await chromium.executablePath;

  let browser = null;

  browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath,
    headless: true
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  page.setContent(html);

  const pdf = await page.pdf({
    format: "A4",
    printBackground: true,
    margin: { top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm", left: "1cm" }
  });


  const output_filename = 'pdf-demo.pdf';

  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: Bucket_name + '/' + 'pdf',
    Key: `epiconnect/pdfs/${output_filename}`,
    Body: pdf,
    ContentType: "application/pdf",
    ServerSideEncryption: "AES256"
  };

  await s3.upload(s3Params, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
      return callBack(null, { error });
    }
  });

} catch (err) {

  console.log(err);
  return context.fail(err);

}
```

Comment: Does the code succeed when you run it locally? If there are no indications of errors in the logs, but the function isn't working, then you need to add more logging. I also notice that you are mixing async/await and callbacks, which I believe is going to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @sepp2k / @Shazam,
                       I think the issue here is that you are using await in front of `s3.upload` that isn't returning a promise, try changing thi

```
  await s3.upload(s3Params, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
      return callBack(null, { error });
    }
  });
```

to the promise version

```
  await s3.upload(s3Params).promise();
```

Thx!